# React js can't access array useState by index, map works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```js
export interface JobListing {
  id: number,
  isTraded: boolean,
  feedback: string,
  title: string,
  message: string,
  skills: string[],
  sender: string,
  ipAddress: string
}


const GroupList = () => {

const [jobListings, setJobListings] = useState<JobListing[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    database.collection("job_listings").onSnapshot((snapshot: any) => (
      setJobListings(snapshot.docs.map((doc: any) => doc.data()))
    ));
    alert(jobListings[0].message)
    return () => {
    }
  }, [])

  return ('JSX code')
}
export default GroupList;
```

I have useEffect where I am setting my listings by useState hook from firebase.
Everythink works fine when I am using map to iterate over
jobListings and returning table cell for each one in JSX component.
However whenever in code I want access jobListings[some_index].message
I am getting **Cannot read property 'message' of undefined**. For example
in alert in code.
As you see I am using typescript and have type for jobListings.
When I set up instead empty array some item with appropriate properties,
I was able to access index 0 jobListings[0].message.

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet, the problem is that your `onSnapshot` callback runs after `alert`. If you want to print the first item of the array, do that in the `onSnapshot` callback itself

```js
useEffect(() => {
    database.collection("job_listings").onSnapshot((snapshot: any) => (
      const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc: any) => doc.data())
      setJobListings(data)
      // `jobListings` is still empty at this point, it's updated at the next render cycle
      alert(data[0].message)
    ));
    return () => {
    }
  }, [])
```

Comment: I want it printed in return in GroupList functional component,
its inside ModalChild passed as props, I can jobListings.map((postDetail: any, index: any) => {postDetail.message} but can't access by index, alert was just example, it should be rerendered in return

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand what you mean, can you show me more of your code? in the `return` statement of GroupList component you can indeed return JSX code of the jobListings, i.e.: `return <div>{jobListings[0].message}</div>`. Is this failing? You said something about props, are you passing props to GroupList component and it's not updating?

Comment: I have found that jobListings[0]?.message works. How can I solve it without ? with typing?

Comment: As per your code, you shouldn't need the `?`, though try to add a `if (jobListings.length) {}`, or in JSX `{jobListings && <div>{jobListings[0].message}</div>}`